# SFTP private key Connection in java

Tags: java

I am working in a project which we need to connect Client SFTP server using SSH private key instead of password. We using the Apache VFS package to connect to SFTP server but during the SSH connection we have the option to refer the private key(.ssh/ID_RSA.ser) as a File. The disadvantage is we need to refer the private key in a particular server(Tomcat Server) path as a File every time during the SFTP connection is it any other way to authenticate Private key without referring as file ?

Comment: You need to place your ***public*** key on the server with the application. What's wrong with that? Also, putting it in the application classpath doesn't require you to choose one directory

Comment: My question is can we authenticate private key as String or stream instead of file(java.io.File) ? The Public-Private key generate and will share the public key to Customer server and private key we store in Oracle DB and every time we need to connect to Customer server we need to download private key from DB to tomcat server and then make ssh connection so is there any simple way of doing it?

Comment: Again, you should never distribute the private key. It's the public key that authenticates. If you need reauthorization with different keys, I think you're using the wrong mechanisms. But anyway,  you have the API methods. Can you load a String object?
 Obviously you can load a string into a temporary File object, so the answer is yes